# Multiple ID whith one rule

Tags: css

I typed this

```
   #center-1, #center-2, #center-2, #center-3, #center-4,
   #center-5, #center-6, #center-7, #center-8 { float: left; width:360px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="centerColumn"> 
 <div id="center-1"></div> 
 <div id="center-2"></div> 
 <div id="center-3"></div> 
 <div id="center-4"></div> 
 <div id="center-5"></div> 
 <div id="center-6"></div> 
 <div id="center-7"></div> 
 <div id="center-8"></div> 
</div>
```

and it doesn't work, why?

Comment: can show an example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: are dashes valid in an html id attribute?

Comment: Dashes or Hyphens are valid characters in HTML ID or CSS, so it's no issue in this code. Can you upload your page ? Chances are either IDs are not same or you have overwritten CSS.

Comment: but it's work for me check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/RBA5r/ may be there is an other issue

Answer (score 3):

Guessing from your report that it "doesn't work", you're probably just not *seeing* the divs because there is no content, height, or padding. Add `height:10px;` or something, and some background - [they will show up](http://jsfiddle.net/CnxAa/).

By the way, there's a [slightly easier way](http://jsfiddle.net/CnxAa/1/) to write this selector in your case:

```
/* Select all <div>s in the #centerColumn */
#centerColumn div {
    float: left;
    width:360px;

    /* Test to make divs appear */
    background:#f00;
    height:10px;
    margin:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your divs do not have any content, that's why they are not visible. to make them visible add at least a `&nbsp;` into them, or add height/min-height to the css rule